# Cannot psql into docker postgres image port forwarded locally

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, cmd, psql

I'm continuously hitting an error when trying to psql into a docker composed postgres image that has its ports forwarded. (this issue seems to persist also when attempting to access the DB programatically via node application).

Running `docker-compose up -d` on the following docker compose file:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: cnc-matches
    image: postgres:12.1-alpine
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dbuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: cnc-matches
```

When running psql to attempt to access it I hit the following error continuously:

```
C:\Users\danie\Desktop\dev\cnc-db\db-setup>psql -h "localhost" -p "5432" -U dbuser
Password for user dbuser: pass
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dbuser"
```

When running docker exec I'm able to access the table and info fine:

```
C:\Users\danie\Desktop\dev\cnc-db\db-setup>docker exec -it cnc-matches psql -U dbuser cnc-matches
psql (12.1)
Type "help" for help.

cnc-matches=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 dbuser    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

I've tried creating a new user as well as altering the dbuser profiles passwords in here with ALTER PASSWORD dbuser WITH PASSWORD 'pass' and I still cannot access the db with default psql command locally.

```
cnc-matches=# CREATE USER tester WITH PASSWORD 'tester';
CREATE ROLE
cnc-matches=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 dbuser    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 tester    |                                                            | {}

C:\Users\danie\Desktop\dev\cnc-db\db-setup>psql -h "localhost" -p "5432" -U tester
Password for user tester: tester
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "tester"
```

Not sure what it is I'm misisng here, if relevant running via windows 11 cmd.
Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you also need to include the database name when connecting to the database running in the Docker container, ex

```bash
psql -h "0.0.0.0" -p "5432" -U dbuser cnc-matches
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but still get the same issue: 

```C:\Users\danie\Desktop\dev\cnc-db\db-setup>psql -h "localhost" -p "5432" -U dbuser cnc-matches
Password for user dbuser:
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dbuser"
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated the answer

Comment: NP, the revised response returns a different error -> `psql: error: connection to server at "0.0.0.0", port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address (0x00002741/10049)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?` afaik trying with 127.0.0.1 or localhost should yield the same results, Im not certain its the specification of the -h thats the issue as it states the auth is the issue as opposed to not having the right hostname

Comment: You might want to try removing the container with `docker rm cnc-matches` (as long as you don't need any data already stored in it), starting the compose stack again with `docker-compose up -d`, and attempting to connect again. If you've changed some of the environment variables in the past, it doesn't look like new changes will take effect after the first time the container spins up. You can read more about that here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Ryan, I use docker-compose down each time I go to re-run it which seems to clear the containers, theres no persistent cnc-matches table data configured (not specified in docker file) so not the suspected root cause here. The 0.0.0.0 appears invalid, the localhost value for host seems valid but auth still failing... still uncertain the root issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the container was successfully started, try running:

`psql -U dbuser -d cnc-matches -h 0.0.0.0 --port 5432`

For the port use whatever you mapped yours in the container to; in your case 5432.

You must specify all that explicitly or else you will get an error that the database cannot accept TCP/IP connections.

Answer (score -1):

First time I am posting, sorry if there is wrong formatting.
I updated your docker-compose file with a network bridge as still isolated from the network with the host machine.

Steps:

"db-net" can be any name you want but both must coincide with your docker compose file

1. Create a docker network with: docker network create db-net
2. Run: docker-compose up -d

   ```html
   version: "3.9"
   services:
     postgresCNC:
       container_name: cnc-matches
       image: postgres:15.0-alpine
       ports:
         - '5432:5432'
       environment:
         POSTGRES_USER: dbuser
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
         POSTGRES_DB: cnc-matches
       networks:
         db-net:

   networks:
     db-net:
       driver: bridge
   ```

Network bridge by default uses the hardware network device to communicate between containers and host machine as with containers with others containers.
More info here:
https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: This doesn't seem to be especially related to the issue described in the question.  Docker networks aren't used for connections from outside Docker, and the Docker networking setup doesn't obviously affect `psql`'s password authentication once it does successfully connect to the database server.

Comment: gave this a shot, still get the same auth errors unfortunately. - as mentioned by David this shouldnt impact psql's auth

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).